# React pass variables between functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component that I am trying to build. addEntry detects when the user submits a data entry, and RenderTable should render each entry in a table row format:

```
import React, { useState, setState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'function 

function addEntry({ addEntryData }) {
  const data = [{
    First: "aaa",
    Last: "bbb",
    Phone: 123123
  }];
  const [contact, setContact] = useState(data);

  const submitEntry = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setContact(contact.push({
      First: e.target.userFirstname.value,
      Last: e.target.userLastname.value,
      Phone: e.target.userPhone.value
    }))
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitEntry} style={style.form.container}>
      <input 
        className='userFirstname'
        name='userFirstname' 
        type='text'
      />
      <input 
        className='userLastname'
        name='userLastname' 
        type='text' 
      />
      <input
        className='userPhone' 
        name='userPhone' 
        type='text'
      />
      <input 
        className='submitButton'
        type='submit' 
        value='Add User' 
      />
    </form>
  )
};

function RenderTable(props) {
  return (
    <table className='informationTable'>
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>First name</th>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>Last name</th>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead> 
    </table>
  );
}

function Application(props) {
  return (
    <section>
      <addEntry/>
      <RenderTable/>
    </section>
  );
```

I would like to pass the `contact` data from `addEntry` to `RenderTable`, so `RenderTable` could generate some rows. But I have tried props or calling `RenderTable(contact)`. `Contact` seems to live only inside `addEntry`, and not `RenderTable`. What should I do such that `RenderTable` could read the values stored in the `contact` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few solutions to this problem. Probably the easiest one is to create a `useState` in `Application` component, pass the update function to `addEntry` (suggestion: name it `AddEntry`) and the state to `RenderTable`. Basically, move your state from `addEntry` to `Application` component. I presume that the table will contain list of contacts.

```
function Application(props) {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  return (
    <section>
      <addEntry setContacts={setContacts}/>
      <RenderTable contacts={contacts}/>
    </section>
  );
```

And for `addEntry` add the prop `setContacts`:

```
function addEntry({ addEntryData, setContacts }) {
   const submitEntry = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     setContacts((contacts) => [...contacts, {
       First: e.target.userFirstname.value,
       Last: e.target.userLastname.value,
       Phone: e.target.userPhone.value
     }])
   }
  ... 
}
```

Cleaner solution: Use some global state management library such as Redux or React context.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, why doesn't `Application(props)` re-render or re-run, each time I execute setContacts ?

Answer (score 0):

Time to start using some kind of global state management tool where you can handle the state among components. My suggestion to you is start by using Context to understand how it works, and later on, jump into Redux or Flux. If you decide not to use any of these tools, you are going to have to use props. Props are passed from parent component to child, so in your case, the component that holds AddEntry and RenderTable, Application in your case, will hold the state and other functions to modify the state. Then you need to pass the state and functions as props to the child components.